# In C, How do I place functions in a section and not prevent them from being optimized out

Tags: function, gcc, memory

I'm working on an embedded project: ARMv7 with GCC.
I've been placing code in RAM so that it can run fast, I'm running out of RAM, so I have to start compromising. I can run code from multiple memory locations like:

- Flash ( slow but plentiful )
- Normal RAM ( pretty fast, but limited in size )
- ITCM ( faster than ram but very limited in size. )
- external QSPI flash
- etc....

What I want to accomplish is to distribute my code across the different memory types based on the particular needs of a particular piece of code.
Let's look at the following 2 functions:

```
void func_1(){ do-something time-critical ... }
void func_2(){ do-something else also time critical ... }
```

Without doing anything else, my somewhat standard linker file looks like this:

```
.text :
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text .text.* )
    *(.glue_7t) *(.glue_7)  
    .
    .
    .
} > rom
```

After compiling and linking the .map file looks something like this:

```
.text.func_1
    0x0044ba90      0x58 /src/some_file.0
.text.func_2
    0x0044bae8      0x78 /src/some_file.0
```

At this point, everything is great and very importantly, if for example func_2() is not called from any code, it gets optimized out.

When I start placing functions in their appropriate memory regions, I modify them like so:

```
__attribute__ ((section(".ramfunc")))
void func_1(){ do-something... }

__attribute__ ((section(".ramfunc")))
void func_2(){ do-something else ... }
```

I would then use my linker file to place the "fast_run" section in RAM for example

```
.relocate :
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _srelocate = .;
    *(.ramfunc .ramfunc.*);
    .
    .
    .
} >ram AT>rom
```

After compiling and linking the .map file looks something like this:

```
.ramfunc    0x2040f000      0x136 /src/some_file.0
            0x2040f000               func_1
            0x2040f058               func_2
```

The functions are now in RAM and that is fine, but instead of having their own subsections inside .ramfunc they are all **in** .ramfunc
Initially I thought that was fine, but with that arrangement, even if no other portions of my program calls func_2 it doesn't get optimized.

I'm assuming that by loosing the sub-section names, I am preventing the linker from "optimizing stuff out"
How do I fix that? I want to be able to place functions in the appropriate memory regions, but still allow them to be optimized out if not used.
Is there a way to place functions in sections while preserving their sub-section name?

I searched through the documentation for **attribute**((section)) but could not find anything useful.
I also tried finding an explanation about how those subsections in the form of .text.func_1 are generated and if I could affect the process but again I could not find a solution.

Using something like this:

```
.relocate :
{
    .
    .
    /src/fast_code.o (.text .text.* )
} >ram AT>rom
```

works great of course, but acts on entire files and lacks the per-function granularity that I'm trying to achieve for certain parts of my code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this GCC compiler option can help: -ffunction-sections. It will create separate section for each function. There is a similar option to handle data sections.

The linker only discards sections if --gc-sections is specified.

And finally, the startup code, reset vector and other important stuff that has no references to it might be discarded. To prevent that, use the KEEP() directive in the linker files, e.g.:
KEEP(*(.text.boot));